# change theme and add header to a google test via api

Tags: php, forms, google-api, google-forms, google-forms-api

I'm interested in finding out if there's a method or a workaround to modify the background color and header image via an API. I can duplicate an existing form for all other aspects, but I'm facing challenges with these specific settings.

Thank you in advance!

It seems that even through Apps Script, it's not quite possible. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently change the theme or add a header to a Google Forms survey through the API or Apps Script.

You can try creating a new Google Form with your desired theme and header, then duplicating your existing quiz questions in the new form. This will create a new quiz with the same questions but a different theme and header.